# Validating a user is 18

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core-2.1

I used Tahir Naushad [ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC Model Validation](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1204077/ASP-NET-Core-MVC-Model-Validation) to create the following:

From Register page:

```
   public class FDRegisterModel : PageModel
{

    private readonly SignInManager<FDUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly UserManager<FDUser> _userManager;
    private readonly ILogger<FDRegisterModel> _logger;
    private readonly IEmailService _emailSender;

    public FDRegisterModel(
        UserManager<FDUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<FDUser> signInManager,
        ILogger<FDRegisterModel> logger,
        IEmailService emailSender
        )
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }



    public class InputModel
    {
        ...
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [AgeCheck]
        [Display(Name = "Date of birth:")]
        public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var FDuser = new FDUser { UserName = Input.UserName, Email = Input.Email };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(FDuser, Input.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation(Input.UserName + "was created.");

                var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(FDuser);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                    "/Profile/ConfirmEmail",
                    pageHandler: null,
                    values: new { FDUsername = FDuser.UserName, code = code },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme);

                await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                    $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(FDuser, isPersistent: false);
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
}
```

From FDUser model:

```
public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
```

From AgeCheck model:

```
public class AgeCheck : ValidationAttribute
{
    //public DateTime Eighteen = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-6570);
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

    private string GetErrorMessage()
    {
        return $"Users of this website must be eighteen years of age.";
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(
        object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var model = validationContext.ObjectInstance as FDUser;

        if (model == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("No birthday given");

        if (model.Birthday > DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-6570))
            return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage(validationContext));

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    private string GetErrorMessage(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ErrorMessage))
            return this.ErrorMessage;

        return $"Users of this website must be eighteen years of age.";
    }
}
```

It returns `null`:

[Age check error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i87iP.jpg)

I also looked at [Microsofts article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and I'd love to have something more simplistic like this:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    if (Birthday > Eighteen)
    {
        return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage());
    }

    return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

But I can't get that to working either.

Comment: I guess `validationContext.ObjectInstance` is the object defined in the register page, not `FDUser`.

Comment: Birthday is the same sure variable for the FDUser for both the Register page and the FDUser model. (Register page pushing the form that I want validated through the FDUser model. (which is inherited from the IdentityUser Model) It's a Razor page code-behind page for the registration page.

Comment: Shingo I added more register snippet. I get "can't find" error with RegisterModel. or FDRegisterModel. In Tahir creates and references a model(like FDUser), but he has additional code in the controller of 
    [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Save(EmployeeInputModel model)
        {
            // simulate DB call to check existence of Id
            if (model.Id == 1)
                ModelState.AddModelError("Id", "Id already exist");

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
                return Ok(model);

            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

Comment: Your `AgeCheck` validation attribute is running against `InputModel` rather than `FDUser`, so `validationContext.ObjectInstance` is of type `InputModel` and not `FDUser`, which is why the cast fails.

Comment: Kirk, could you explain a bit more, please? I get this when I try to change it to InputModel. https://i.imgur.com/1TtYAZH.jpg

Comment: I was just explaining why you get the error. Your screenshot error is because you've got a lowercase `m` in `InputModel`. You can fix that and then use the relevant namespace, but you don't need to be dealing with `InputModel` at all as you *only care about the single `Birthday` property of `DateTime`*. The second approach you've described in your OP is the way to go here - try explaining more about why that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Kirk I used the second more simplistic option and was able to get it working with this code. (the extra days are for leap year if you're curious why the math doesn't look right)

```
public sealed class AgeCheck : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public DateTime Birthday;
        public DateTime Eighteen = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-6573);

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object Birthday, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (Eighteen <= Convert.ToDateTime(Birthday))
            {
                return new ValidationResult("You must be eighteen to use this website");
            }
            else
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
        }
    }
```